# Работа с двумерным массивом в классах с наследованием C++

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, наследование

Есть базовый класс А в *public* которого находится двумерный массив *char Pole[H][W]*.
Есть класс B (наследуемый от А) в методе (*SetW*) которого происходит работа с char *Pole[H][W]*.

```
void SetW()
{//работа с массивом//}
```

Есть класс С (тоже наследуемый от А) в методе (*SetS*) которого должна происходить работа с char *Pole[H][W]*.

```
void SetS()
{//работа с массивом//}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы оба метода могли работать с одним и тем же массивом?
Наверное нужно как-то работать с ссылками или указателями (но это не точно).
Если можно, то, пожалуйста, как можно подробнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно объявить этот массив как статический член базового класса. И тогда все объекты этого базового и производных классов будут иметь дело с одним и тем же массивом.

В противно случае ваш дизайн классов не имеет смысла. То есть придется изначально менять определение базового класса и вместо массива вводит указатель или ссылку на внешний по отношению к объектам класса массив.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. 
В классе написал static char Pole[H][W].
Вне класса добавил char A::Pole[H][W];

Comment: @Nikita.L Не за что.